# Assigning a value to a variable with the scanf function

Tags: c, scanf, variable-assignment

No matter what value I enter for x, the output for the value of y is always 1. Any ideas why?

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main() {
    int x, y;
    y = scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("y = %d\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A [good `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might be helpful. Especially read about what it returns. Oh and *think* a little, if you had a format string with multiple conversions (like e.g. `"%d %d"`), how would `scanf` be able to return all the values then? Reading [a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should also be very good.

Comment: Read the manpage for scanf.  You read one value.  Of course y = 1/

Comment: @xing entering `abc` with this code is UB

Comment: You are right by saying that printing 'y' wouldn't be ub but reading string with the %d format is ub by itself. Before invoking the printf

Comment: @CIsForCookies: Whoa, hold up - entering `"abc"` for *this code* would not be undefined behavior - it would be a *matching failure*, and `scanf` would return 0, leaving `"abc"` in the input stream.  That's well-defined.  What's UB is using an argument type other than `int *` for the `%d` conversion specifier.

Comment: @JohnBode Thanks for that, I thought `scanf` had no check for these kind of bad iputs

Comment: @CIsForCookies:  It’s not perfect - if you enter `”1bc”`, the `%d` specifier will convert and assign the `1`, leaving `”bc”` in the input stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [scanf(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

> These functions ***return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned***, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

Since `scanf` return value is the number of items written (in your case, 1, since only 1 `int` was scanned), not the integer value of the scanned character

```
int main() {
    int x, y, z, n;
    n = scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);                 // prints 1
    n = scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);                 // prints 2
    n = scanf("%d%d%d", &x, &y,&z);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);                 // prints 3
    return 0;
}
```